# Linker error when compiling PJSIP on iOS 7 sdk and xcode 5

Tags: ios, linker, makefile, xcode5, pjsip

I am getting this linker error when compiling PJSIP with iOS 7 SDK (xcode 5.0.2, Mavericks 10.9.1).

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_aes_icm_advance_ismacryp", referenced from:
      _aes_icm_encrypt_ismacryp in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(aes_icm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjmedia-test-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjmedia-test] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download prebuilt pjsip library (armv7, armvs7, arm64, i386) from cocoapods using `pod 'pjsip'` or by compiling it by yourself running `build.sh` script from https://github.com/chebur/pjsip

Comment: I use your second suggestion and build ok. but when embeded in my just a small ios project, it build fail! console shows "Endianness must be declared for this processor", "PJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN is not defined!" and "PJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN is not defined!". do you know why?

Comment: You have to define your own preprocessor macros `PJ_AUTOCONF=1` for Xcode's "Preprocessor Macros" configuration. Also see this thread http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2011-November/013750.html